# The callout couldn't access the endpoint. You might not have the required permissions, or the named credential

Tags: apex, httprequest, namedcredentials, http

I have created a named credentials which has a endpoint like this and it is authenticated

```
https://#######-#####.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=####&deploy=1
```

while making a callout i want to add a url parameter like below

```
&InternalId=111111111
```

So the call out from apex is looking like this

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:namedcredentials&InternalId=111111111');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setTimeOut(60000);
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
System.debug('resp ' + response.getBody());
```

But its thowing error like

```
The callout couldn't access the endpoint. You might not have the required permissions, or the named credential
```

Any idea where things are going wrong . I am running it as sys admin .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the URL structure in your callout endpoint.

The Named Credential URL and the query string need to be separated by a `?` like the following:

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:namedcredential?InternalId=111111111');
```

If you have multiple attributes you're sending in the URL then you'd separate those with a `&` like the following:

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:namedcredential?InternalId=111111111&Attribute2=2');
```

Reference: [Named Credentials as Callout Endpoints](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.244.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm)